# Can the kitchen drain/trap/pipe be rotated 45 degrees?

Tags: kitchen-sink, old-pipes

In my area, kitchen drain pipes go toward the back wall of the house. When and if there are problems, either the interior wall, sink, and counter top OR the rear exterior wall of the house needs to be removed to gain access for repair or replacement.
I was thinking maybe I could turn the trap 45 degrees, drill through the floor, put in new PVC and tying into the existing pipe in the basement, bypassing the pipe in the wall.

[image: Three pictures combined]

Comment: They are made to fit/turn to the drain pipe in any direction.  90% of problems happen right below the sink(leaks).  Usually blockages can be removed with snakes from below the sink.  Might just be a make work for little benefit.

Comment: I'll take that under advisement. The way we discovered that the pipe was leaking was because of water running down the wall inside the basement. We looked for water under the sink, on the kitchen floor, behind the dishwasher and refrigerator. Nothing. This all happened yesterday. I didn't see or notice the wetness on the exterior wall until today. Sounds like I should be able to turn that trap, and reroute that pipe though?

Comment: Can turn it any way you want even coming straight out into the kitchen(won't look nice).  Drain pipes are not under pressure(minor leaks, drips).  Might want to check the supply pipes which are under pressure all the time(major leaks, more than drips).  You seem to have more than a drip.

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: I'd second the concern about being sure whether it's supply or drain that's leaking before looking to rearrange plumbing. You might end up doing a lot of work and not fixing the problem. If you do rearrange drain plumbing remember that it's called "DWV" - "Drain, Waste, _Vent_". You'll need to accommodate the ventilation portion (and remain within code) to keep your drains running properly and not let sewer gas back into the house.

Comment: Thanks for that comment remember that it's called "DWV" - "Drain, Waste, Vent"
Can't remember because I didn't know about it. Glad I waited and didn't run off to the hardware store like I had planned. I was going to cap the pipe in the wall BUT was going to merely cut the pipe in the basement and connect PVC on top. I'm wondering if I cut still cut the pipe but do something like a TEE to allow the water from the kitchen to drain into that existing pipe but leave it connected so that if there is a vent from there, it will stay connected. How's that sound?

Comment: I'll also mention again that other homes in our area have had this issue. For some reason I guess it was popular to run this one particular pipe back into the cinder block and then back down into the basement rather than down through the kitchen floor. It ends up in a similar location. Without tearing out brick, I suspect that the vent is later in the line and go up to the roof.

Comment: You don't say whether there's anything above the kitchen that may need the CIP vent retained.  You'll be creating an S-trap under the sink, but you can use an AAV.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fight the general problem of failure of pipes that are hidden inside stud walls, then yes you can design and build a system that minimizes the use of wall cavities for running pipes. They would all be run on the surface, along walls and ceilings.  I think considering how rarely these failures occur, most people would not want this unless they were going for that specific aesthetic.

If you want to do it only in very specific situations where you have a plumbing fixture directly above an unfinished room, such as a kitchen sink over a basement, sure you can do that. But 1) statistics are working against you. Now you're not planning just for a rare occurrence of a pipe failing, but of that one specific one failing! Which it won't of course, because you're paying so much attention to it.  And 2) You're creating venting challenges.  And 3) your contribution to not having to break open walls, is only to about 18 inches of kitchen wall already hidden inside an under sink cabinet where it doesn't have to be refinished very well.

So I think the basic answer to your question is, "no", you should not switch a p-trap to an inferior s-trap, creating new problems and providing almost no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

If you disconnect from the wall pipe you will need to provide a new vent after the trap (this could be a correctly installed AAV). you'll also need to cap the wall pipe.

having a leaking vent pipe inside the wall is also worrisome. you shoils probably disconnect that and replace it too if a vent is needed in that part of the plumbing.

Comment: AAVs aren't allowed in all plumbing situations, are flat out banned in some jurisdictions, and are known for failing and needing to be replaced fairly frequently where they are allowed/used. Not necessarily the best solution for venting. Would probably be better to have some extra under sink plumbing to tie into the existing house vent than rely on an AAV.

Comment: the existing vent is inside that wall. maybe it's good despite the drain failing.